# How to realize the choice of only one block, not all blocks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Now when clicking on a picture with a blue boarder, the borderers are painted red in all blocks. How to make so that when you click on a specific block, the stroke is colored only in this block and the text is returned back to "not selected"?

```js
$('.div').click(function() {

  if ( !($('.div').hasClass('selected')) ) {
      $('.div').addClass('selected');
      $('.p').text('selected text');
  } else {
    $('.div').removeClass('selected');
  }
});
```

```css
.div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-480-1.jpg)"></div><p class="p">not selected</p>
<div class="div" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-480-1.jpg)"></div><p class="p">not selected</p>
<div class="div" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-480-1.jpg)"></div><p class="p">not selected</p>
```

Comment: You should probably be using `$(this)` inside your function instead of `$('.div')` again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `click` code refers to: `$(".div")`, which gets all the elements that match that selector. You only want the one that was clicked, which you can get via `$(this)`.

You did the same kind of thing when changing the text - you changed the text of all the elements that matched the `.p` selector. You need to change the text of just the `p` element that is the next element sibling of the `div` that got clicked.

```js
$('.div').click(function() {

  if ( !($(this).hasClass('selected')) ) {
      $(this).addClass('selected');
      $(this.nextElementSibling).text('selected text');
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('selected');
    $(this.nextElementSibling).text('not selected');    
    
  }
});
```

```css
.div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-480-1.jpg)"></div><p class="p">not selected</p>
<div class="div" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-480-1.jpg)"></div><p class="p">not selected</p>
<div class="div" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-480-1.jpg)"></div><p class="p">not selected</p>
```

Comment: This works, but since we're already using jQuery it might make more sense to use `.next()` instead: `$(this).next().text('selected text');`

Comment: Sorry, do you know how to make the stroke turn red when clicking on "p"?